# User can't add empty new row on wpf datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls

At runtime, user can't add new empty row on my wpf datagrid. I tried CanUserAddRow="True", IsReadOnly="False"

XAML

```
<DataGrid x:Name="UrunGrid" Grid.Row="0" CanUserAddRows="True" AlternatingRowBackground="LightGray" AlternationCount = "2" AutomationProperties.IsOffscreenBehavior="Offscreen">
            <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="ISBN/Barkod" Binding="{Binding BARCODE}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Ürün Açıklaması" Binding="{Binding PRODUCT_NAME}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Adet" Binding="{Binding QUANTITY}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="ISK" Binding="{Binding DISCOUNT}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="KDV" Binding="{Binding TAX}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Birim Fiyat" Binding="{Binding PURCHASE_PRICE}"/>
                <DataGridTextColumn Header="Tutar" Binding="{Binding AMOUNT}"/>
            </DataGrid.Columns>
        </DataGrid>
```

Class

```
    class Invoice
{
    public Int64 BARCODE { get; set; }
    public string PRODUCT_NAME { get; set; }

    public int  QUANTITY{ get; set; }

    public int  DISCOUNT{ get; set; }

    public int TAX{ get; set; }

    public int PURCHASE_PRICE { get; set; }

    public int AMOUNT { get; set; }

    public static ObservableCollection<Invoice> getInvoice()
    {
        var invoice = new ObservableCollection<Invoice>();
        return invoice;
    }

}
```

XAML.CS

```
public partial class PurchaseInvoice : Page
{

    private const Visibility visible = Visibility.Visible;
    SqlDataReader dataReader;

    public string cariadi { get; private set; }

    public PurchaseInvoice()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = Invoice.getInvoice();

    }

}
```

I want; users can create a new invoice on this datagrid panel. Each row represent a product. And, how user can control datagrid with arrowkeys?

Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set or bind the `ItemsSource` property of the `DataGrid` to the `ObservableCollection<T>`:

```
<DataGrid x:Name="UrunGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding}" ...
```

Or:

```
UrunGrid.ItemsSource = Invoice.getInvoice();
```